# LINQ: Collapsing a series of strings into a set of "ranges"

Tags: c#, string, linq

I have an array of strings similar to this (shown on separate lines to illustrate the pattern):

```
{ "aa002","aa003","aa004","aa005","aa006","aa007", // note that aa008 is missing
  "aa009"
  "ba023","ba024","ba025"
  "bb025",
  "ca002","ca003",
  "cb004",
   ...}
```

...and the goal is to collapse those strings into this comma-separated string of "ranges":

```
"aa002-aa007,aa009,ba023-ba025,bb025,ca002-ca003,cb004, ... "
```

I want to collapse them so I can construct a URL.  There are hundreds of elements, but I can still convey all the information if I collapse them this way - putting them all into a URL "longhand" (it has to be a GET, not a POST) isn't feasible.

I've had the idea to separate them into groups using the first two characters as the key - but does anyone have any clever ideas for collapsing those sequences (without gaps) into ranges?  I'm struggling with it, and everything I've come up with looks like spaghetti.

Comment: Even if it's possible in LINQ, I'd do it without LINQ, mainly so that it's maintainable and readable for future developers.

Comment: @AdrianThompsonPhillips The *purpose* of LINQ is to write queries that are readable and maintainable...

Comment: I find linq to be more readable, usually.  The intention is quite clear by the syntax.  That being said, I'd be happy with any solution, not just a LINQ one.

Comment: @Servy exactly, the above problem could probably be solved by a bored academic mind, but I bet the result wouldn't be readable.  I am willing to be proven wrong :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the first thing that you need to do is parse the strings.  It's important to have the alphabetic prefix and the integer value separately.

Next you want to group the items on the prefix.

For each of the items in that group, you want to order them by number, and then group items while the previous value's number is one less than the current item's number.  (Or, put another way, while the previous item plus one is equal to the current item.)

Once you've grouped all of those items you want to project that group out to a value based on that range's prefix, as well as the first and last number.  No other information from these groups is needed.

We then flatten the list of strings for each group into just a regular list of strings, since once we're all done there is no need to separate out ranges from different groups.  This is done using `SelectMany`.

When that's all said and done, that, translated into code, is this:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> Foo(IEnumerable<string> data)
{
    return data.Select(item => new
            {
                Prefix = item.Substring(0, 2),
                Number = int.Parse(item.Substring(2))
            })
            .GroupBy(item => item.Prefix)
            .SelectMany(group => group.OrderBy(item => item.Number)
                    .GroupWhile((prev, current) =>
                        prev.Number + 1 == current.Number)
                    .Select(range =>
                        RangeAsString(group.Key,
                            range.First().Number,
                            range.Last().Number)));
}
```

The `GroupWhile` method can be implemented like so:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> GroupWhile<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, T, bool> predicate)
{
    using (var iterator = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (!iterator.MoveNext())
            yield break;

        List<T> list = new List<T>() { iterator.Current };

        T previous = iterator.Current;

        while (iterator.MoveNext())
        {
            if (!predicate(previous, iterator.Current))
            {
                yield return list;
                list = new List<T>();
            }

            list.Add(iterator.Current);
            previous = iterator.Current;
        }
        yield return list;
    }
}
```

And then the simple helper method to convert each range into a string:

```
private static string RangeAsString(string prefix, int start, int end)
{
    if (start == end)
        return prefix + start;
    else
        return string.Format("{0}{1}-{0}{2}", prefix, start, end);
}
```

Comment: Very cool GroupWhile extension!! Was thinking of a loop myself.

Comment: @AD.Net It's not something you need to do a ton, but [it has a fair number of uses](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A1159478+GroupWhile)

Comment: IMO I think it would read more naturally if you removed the initial `GroupBy` and instead order by `Prefix` then `Number` and call `GroupWhile` directly on that (adding the "if in same prefix" check there). Seems like the grouping logic should be in one place, and the input list seems to come sorted that way anway.

Comment: @Ocelot20 The problem there is that it doesn't fit as naturally in the native requirements, nor does it map to how I would attempt to solve the problem "by hand" as effectively.  Yes, it removes the use of `SelectMany`, but at the cost of a more complex predicate to `GroupWhile`.  Personally I prefer this, although that change isn't completely out of the question.

Comment: @Servy: That rationale makes sense. I guess I favor what (IMO) looks "cleaner" if the logic is still easy to follow vs. the initial "by hand" interpretation (by the way, that's not my spite downvote for disagreeing!).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a LINQ version without the need to add new extension methods:

```
        var data2 = data.Skip(1).Zip(data, (d1, d0) => new
        {
            value = d1,
            jump = d1.Substring(0, 2) == d0.Substring(0, 2)
                ? int.Parse(d1.Substring(2)) - int.Parse(d0.Substring(2))
                : -1,
        });

        var agg = new { f = data.First(), t = data.First(), };

        var query2 =
            data2
                .Aggregate(new [] { agg }.ToList(), (a, x) =>
                {
                    var last = a.Last();
                    if (x.jump == 1)
                    {
                        a.RemoveAt(a.Count() - 1);
                        a.Add(new { f = last.f, t = x.value, });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        a.Add(new { f = x.value, t = x.value, });
                    }
                    return a;
                });

        var query3 =
            from q in query2
            select (q.f) + (q.f == q.t ? "" : "-" + q.t);
```

I get these results:

[image: results]